# Reverting last auto update for iOS version

Tags: ios, iphone, auto-update

My iOS phone unexpectedly updated OS from version 9.1 to version 9.2. I have no backup for previous versions. Is there any way to revert my last auto update and go back to iOS version 9.1?

Comment: This link may help you : http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/09/downgrade-ios-9-2-to-ios-9-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find OS version 9.1. Choose suitable one for your device.
http://www.iphonehacks.com/2015/10/ios-9-1-download.html